# Frequencies in a vector or list using counts()

Tags: julia

How can i use counts() to show the frequencies and the items? for example:

```
a=[1,2,2,3]
count(a) gives 1,2,1
```

How can i do to get:
`1:1, 2:2, 3:1`?

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking specifically about the `StatsBase.counts()` function?

Comment: not really.  i just need to get the number and its frequencies. any function that can get the job done xD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are already using [`StatsBase`](https://juliastats.org/StatsBase.jl/stable/), because that is where the [`counts`](https://juliastats.org/StatsBase.jl/stable/counts/#StatsBase.counts) function you mention is defined. The function you are looking for is called [`countmap`](https://juliastats.org/StatsBase.jl/stable/counts/#StatsBase.countmap):

```
using StatsBase
a = [1,2,2,3];
countmap(a)
# Dict{Int64, Int64} with 3 entries:
#   2 => 2
#   3 => 1
#   1 => 1
```

Comment: thanks. I was looking in the rigth place but didn't find it xD

Answer (score 3):

If you prefer tabular output you can also do:

```
julia> using FreqTables

julia> a = [1,2,2,3];

julia> freqtable(a)
3-element Named Vector{Int64}
Dim1  │ 
──────┼──
1     │ 1
2     │ 2
3     │ 1
```